# Get a specific id from a table in mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, security

I need to get an id value from a table where the primary key from that table matches the current UserId. I'm using the entityframework/mvc login tables(UserProfile, UsersInRoles, and Roles), but I have another table which is called CompanyUser which doesn't have a relationship with UserProfile. And I cant create a relationship between them because of how the project is built.

In my CompanyUser table I have column UserID and CompanyID, The UserID is the exact same as UserID in the Table UserProfile. So what I need to do but don't know how other then that I can use .equals or .where, is to get the specific CompanyID where UserID inside the same table matches with websecurity.currentUserID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear, but I suspect you just want:

```
var currentUserId = websecurity.CurrentUserID;
var companyId = db.Companies
                  .Where(x => x.UserID == currentUserId)
                  .Select(x => x.CompanyID)
                  .Single();
```

Change `Single` to `First` or `FirstOrDefault` if you don't know that there'll be a matching record, or if there may be more than one.

Comment: I think this will work, since im working with reposity and services just have to get the database in another way, gonna try it out now

Comment: @user2043267: I didn't really follow that, but if this *doesn't* work, you'll need to give us a lot more information about why, and how your code is structured. (And someone else will have to answer, as I'm about to set off on a flight.)

Comment: No worries, im pretty sure the code will work, problem is that this code is in login->accountcontroller, and when i debug it it says that my currentUserId is -1, which doesnt make sence when it should be 1, when i get the right value in currentuserid the code will work